# Connecting mongodb to java project in Eclipse IDE (MacOS)

Tags: java, mongodb, eclipse, macos, jdbc

I'm trying to connect mongodb to my java project in eclipse. I've mentioned the code I've written following some instructions on youtube and the official mongodb documentation.

Below are the .jar files I've added to the project build path.
[Project Properties/Build Path/JRE Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQrnJ.png)

```
package mongoConnect;

import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MongoDatabase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            com.mongodb.client.MongoClient client = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            DB db1 = mongo.getDB("collegemanagementsystem"); 
//error saying "mongo cannot be resolved" in mongo.getDB
            DBCollection col1 = db1.getCollection("Student");
            BasicDBObject d1 = new BasicDBObject("name", "Sabiha").append("age", "23");
            BasicDBObject d2 = new BasicDBObject("name", "Abdullah").append("age", "25");

            col1.insert(d1);
            col1.insert(d2);

            DBCursor cur = col1.find();

            while (cur.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cur.next());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

[The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjNqU.png)

I do have mongodb compass installed if that helps. I also have a local database created in mongodb.

[Mongodb Connection in Mongodb Compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz2x8.png)

My questions are:

1. Is this method different to connecting by jdbc or is this the jdbc method for connecting database to java project?
2. How can I resolve this issue?
3. If this is not the jdbc method how can I connect mongodb to my java project with the jdbc method?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THDfo.png)

Comment: I have stated the error message. It's commented in the code

Comment: What should "mongo" resolve to here?